# Como colocar email no form de login?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Fiz uma aplicação web e mobile.
Após o cadastrado do usuário, estou pegando o email e guardando no localStorage.
Como posso colocar esse email no campo de email do form de login?

```
<ion-view title="Login" hide-back-button="true">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form class="list">
        <ion-list>
            <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="usuario.email" placeholder="E-mail">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="password" ng-model="usuario.senha" placeholder="Senha">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="logar(usuario)">Entrar</button>

            <a href="#/cadastroCep" class="button button-block button-positive">Cadastre-se</a>
            <div align="center">{{msgErro}}</div>
            </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Deixando o `usuario.email` no ng-model não tá funcionando? E não está mostrando nenhum erro no console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o Parazito Respondeu:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope){
    // define no email email@teste.com
    $scope.usuario = {
    "email":"email@teste.com"
    }
```

Comment: OK Guilherme, mas e como jogo o email no formulário, agora?

Comment: Está aqui um exemplo: http://embed.plnkr.co/AwHPJj/

Comment: Consegui ajudar?

Comment: Consegui Guilherme.
Valeu.

Comment: Se quiser mostro com o localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Tento algo assim no seu `loginCtrl`:

```
    .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.usuario = {
        email: $window.localStorage['emailSalvo']
      };
    }
```

Comment: Certo, mas e como eu coloco o email no form de login, após pegar o email?